# What is the replacement of 'scene.render.layers['RenderLayer']' in blender 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting, uv

It seems that the property `scene.render.layers['RenderLayer']` is no longer available in blender-2.8. I just want to set the `use_pass_uv` property of the current scene, then what should I do?

'scene.render.layers['RenderLayer'].use_pass_uv=True' works well in blender-2.7, but in blender-2.8, there was an error like this ''AttributeError: 'RenderSettings' object has no attribute 'layers

Comment: 'scene.render.layers['RenderLayer'].use_pass_uv=True' works well in blender-2.7, but in blender-2.8, there was an error like this ''AttributeError: 'RenderSettings' object has no attribute 'layers'

Comment: You can use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post to modify the text instead of using comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Render layers have been replaced by [View Layers](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/layers/layers.html). Recommend do a search in the [API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/search.html?q=viewlayer&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) or use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out how to access the [ViewLayers](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html#bpy.types.ViewLayer) of the current scene:

```
 >>> C.scene.view_
                 layers
                 settings

>>> for vl in C.scene.view_layers: # Iterate through all view layers
...     print (vl.name) # print the name
...     
View Layer
View Layer.001
View Layer.002
...
```

You can also access the current [ViewLayer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ViewLayer.html#bpy.types.ViewLayer) (in context) by using [bpy.context.view_layer](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html?highlight=view%20layer#bpy.context.view_layer) (or by using `C` convenience variable in the console `C.view_layer`):

```
>>> C.view_layer # View layer reference
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].view_layers["View Layer"]

>>> C.view_layer.name # View layer name
'View Layer.001'
```

Another way is using `get(<LAYERNAME>)` on [`Scene.ViewLayers`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html#bpy.types.Scene.view_layers) collection:

```
>>> C.scene.view_layers.get('View Layer')
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].view_layers["View Layer"]

>>> my_vl = C.scene.view_layers.get('View Layer')
>>> my_vl.name
'View Layer'
```

---

Basic example on how to set attributes of the current view layer (in context):

```
import bpy

# Get the current view layer
vl = bpy.context.view_layer

# Set uv pass attribute
vl.use_pass_uv = True

# Set normal pass attribute
vl.use_pass_normal = True

# Enable diffuse light passes
vl.use_pass_diffuse_direct = True
vl.use_pass_diffuse_indirect = True
vl.use_pass_diffuse_color = True
```

Example on how to enable the 'UV' as well as the 'Normal' pass on all view layers in the scene:

```
import bpy

for vl in bpy.context.scene.view_layers:
    vl.use_pass_uv = True       # Enable UV pass
    vl.use_pass_normal = True   # Enable normal pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply! It helps solving my problem.